# Does this element have an img?

Tags: jquery

Im trying to find out if:

```
$(this)
```

has an img in it.

Something like this, but how do you use it with $(this)?

```
if($('this???:has(img)'))alert('yes');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [.length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) and [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
if($(this).find('img').length)
alert("yes");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
if($(this).find('img').length) alert('yes');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test

```
if ($('img', this).length) alert('yes');
```

More specifically, this alerts if the collection of elements inside this and whose tag is `img` has a non-zero size.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<div id="container">asdasdas
<img/>
</div>


$("#container").click(function(){
if($(this).has("img").length)
{
 alert("yes");
}
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CxNNh/553/)